# Nuxt styled component webpack image from assets directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, styled-components

I create button using [styled components](https://styled-components.com/):

```
import styled from 'vue-styled-components';
const buttonProps = {
  color: String,
  br: String,
  pad: String,
  bgc: String,
  bgch: String,
  icon: String,
};

export default styled('button', buttonProps)`
  color: ${props => props.color};
  border-radius: ${props => props.br};
  padding: ${props => props.pad};
  background-color: ${props => props.bgc};

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${props => props.bgch};
  }

  &::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('~/assets/img/svg/${props => props.icon}');
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
  }
`;
```

I try add `background-image` from `assets` directory but Nuxt return error 404 not found image. When I move image from `assets` to `static` and change in component:

```
...
background-image: url('/${props => props.icon}');
...
```

Image work correctly.

My structure images directory:

[image]

Run button:

```
<TestButton color="#000" br="red" pad="10px" bgc="green" bgch="red" icon="advertisement.svg">aaa</TestButton>
```

How I can send to styled component image from assets ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference them differently

```
background-image: url('/${props => props.icon}'); // is for static
background-image: url('~assets/img/svg/${props => props.icon}'); // is for assets
// or
background-image: url('@assets/img/svg/${props => props.icon}');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, I edit my query, I added screen with structure images directory.

Comment: What do you pass in as icon?

Comment: I send "advertisement.svg"